# Archive files 14 days older in batch by creating same folder structure on different drive

Tags: batch-file, archive

My task is to move all the files which are more than 14 day old to another drive with same folder structure recursively.

Ex:

Source folder: C:\Program Files\Abobe
Destination folder: D:\Projet\Adobe

I have written a script for same however I am getting error while executing

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set SOURCE_DIR=C:\Program Files
set DEST_DIR=D:\Project\x
set FILE_LOC=*.*

for /R "%SOURCE_DIR%" %%F IN (%FILE_LOC%) do (
    if exist "%%F" (
    set FILE_DIR="%%~dpF"
    set FILE_INTERMEDIATE_DIR="!FILE_DIR:%SOURCE_DIR%=!"
    if not exist "%DEST_DIR%!FILE_INTERMEDIATE_DIR!" md "%DEST_DIR%!FILE_INTERMEDIATE_DIR!"
    forfiles /p "%%~dpF" /m *.* /d -14 /c "cmd /c copy /Y @file "%DEST_DIR%!FILE_INTERMEDIATE_DIR!""
)
)
```

After executing the above code following is the error I get,

Type "FORFILES /?" for usage.
ERROR: Invalid argument/option - '/Y'.

Can someone help me to fix this error / code

Answer (score 0):

```
robocopy "%source_dir%" "%target_dir%" * /minage:14 /e /move /l
```

This command should do the work. If the output to console is correct, remove the `/l` switch from command, as it is included to only list the files.